Magento2.4.4p4 REST API Error 'Class string does not exist'
I had this issue during when I create a custom Rest API in fresh magento 2.4.4p4

As you can see the error I get is Class string does not exist
Below are my code folder structure, which I found to be correct already
app/code/Wowshop/MobileAppApi/
├── Api/
│   └── CustomerInterface.php
├── etc/
│   ├── di.xml
│   ├── webapi.xml
│   └── module.xml
├── Model/
│   └── Customer.php
└── registration.php

Please find below content of the 6 file here
app/code/Wowshop/MobileAppApi/Api/CustomerInterface.php
<?php

namespace Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Api;

interface CustomerInterface
{
    /**
     * POST for login API
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return string
     */
    public function login($username,$password);
}

app/code/Wowshop/MobileAppApi/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Api\CustomerInterface" type="Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Model\Customer"/>
</config>

app/code/Wowshop/MobileAppApi/etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Wowshop_MobileAppApi" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>

app/code/Wowshop/MobileAppApi/etc/webapi.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/mobile/customer/login" method="POST">
        <service class="Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Api\CustomerInterface" method="login"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>

app/code/Wowshop/MobileAppApi/Model/Customer.php
<?php

namespace Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Model;

use Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Api\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory;

class Customer implements CustomerInterface
{
    protected $tokenModelFactory;
    protected $customerAccountManagement;
    protected $resultFactory;

    public function __construct(
        TokenFactory $tokenModelFactory,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
    ) {
        $this->tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Accept username and password and return token string
     * @author : Farhan
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return string
     */  
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $username = $this->request->getBodyParams('username');
        $password = $this->request->getBodyParams('password');

        try {
            $customer = $customerAccountManagement->authenticate($username, $password);
            $token = $tokenModelFactory->create();
            $token->createCustomerToken($customer->getId());
            $accessToken = $token->getToken();
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $result->setData(['access_token' => $accessToken]);
            return $result;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            // Handle login failure
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $result->setData(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
            return $result;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle unexpected exceptions
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $result->setData(['message' => 'An error occurred.']);
            return $result;
        }

    }
    
}

I am unable to figure out how to resolve this isssue, from my checking the docblock I put already correct and same as per the CustomerInterface.php and Customer.php
I have tried changing the @param string $username $password in both file to @param string[] $username $password or @param mixed $username $password but none helps as it gives out other error
If request
* @api
* @param string[] $username
* @param string[] $password
* @return string[]

Error
"The \"string\" value's type is invalid. The \"string[]\" type was expected. Verify and try again."


If request
* @api
* @param mixed $username
* @param mixed $password
* @return string

Error
"message": "Class string does not exist",

Please help me understand how this error occur and how to fix this

hi, I have fixed this issue, apparently its because I use redundant code such as getBodyParams, and also resultFactory, once removed its okay already
